# Can this inherited seal be translated? (Characters Identified: 大清乾隆年製)

Tags: character-identification, seal

It is on the base of a large flow blue platter I've inherited and I know nothing about Asian pottery. Since my aunt was quite the collector, I'm assuming it must be old? [image]

Answer (score 3):

大清乾隆年製 Made in Qing Dynasty, during Qianlong's reign (1735 to 1796)

One of the results from Google Image Search: [大清乾隆年製](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%A4%A7%E6%B8%85%E4%B9%BE%E9%9A%86%E5%B9%B4%E8%A3%BD&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsZNOCZ3z226IPklrSX0ixPAFqEEXA:1656609045965&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=XJ0IOe56XtnlBM%252CfgaINk1Zn34lFM%252C_%253B8dNsmqql8mLEjM%252CUcuGlclz2pPFvM%252C_%253B2Ab51MZNLDLKrM%252CFQNORsNHPCylLM%252C_%253B_ZbXuuRdwdYOpM%252C4M5X-kdkZ9-WjM%252C_%253BPHxQw88Aj20t0M%252CFQNORsNHPCylLM%252C_%253B_9wpVcPlWplO9M%252COMveag0dEOH6XM%252C_%253BXRYXuC8fxSChkM%252CVhKlJysdqqBziM%252C_%253Bpess-ZmuIcowdM%252CfgaINk1Zn34lFM%252C_%253BQUb3q9-_Yq8K_M%252C4M5X-kdkZ9-WjM%252C_%253BVDvLNIwD6BT6GM%252CFQNORsNHPCylLM%252C_%253Bw2v1cz67ardjFM%252CUcuGlclz2pPFvM%252C_%253Bkga-Fq1N_xt_RM%252Cmk4xJ9d3E3ZuaM%252C_%253BdjAVWHqc1CfM0M%252Cw8CQ2S1NruPRtM%252C_%253BkUAfY-G7ASRvvM%252C4M5X-kdkZ9-WjM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kTht1HQC5Fn9Vrr67z6uzBSjSmn6g&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgp93N1dX4AhVYRs0KHc0ZCTIQ9QF6BAgEEAE#imgrc=XJ0IOe56XtnlBM)

[image]